# Append current URL to Javascript website badge embed for tracking purposes?

Tags: javascript

My current badge embed looks like this:

```
document.write("<a href='http://www.example.com'><img src='http://www.example.com/badges/badge-large.png'></a>");
```

This is then embedded into other sites with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/badges/badge-large.js"></script>
```

I need to add the current URL of whatever page that embed has been added to to the badge href. I am having trouble getting something to work. Would anyone be kind enough to point me in the right direction? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the current URL, use `document.location.href` like so:

```
document.write("<a href='"+document.location.href+"'><img src='http://www.example.com/badges/badge-large.png'></a>");
```

Comment: I had been trying document.location.href. Just didn't write it quite right. Thank you.